# What are the meanings of "en", "plus", and "fonce" in this context?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, expressions

> « S'il y a la moindre chance d'**en** apprendre **plus** sur l'agonie de la terre, **fonce**. »

1. I understand that the word "en" can be used to replace a "de ..." expression, but I fail to see what the "en" in this sentence refers to. Is it about "apprendre de ..." or "apprendre plus de ..."?

   Considering that the phrase "apprendre plus sur ..." means "learn more about ...", I cannot see why the "en" is necessary here.
2. Does the word "plus" here simply mean "(learn) more (about)"?
3. I understand that the verb "foncer" can be used to mean "dash/bolt", but in this particular context, does the word have a totally different meaning?

Comment: 'en' is an adverbial pronoun in this case.

Comment: <off topic>Unless there is a hidden/personal meaning, what about changing your alias to the less eye hurting "pourrait peut-être"?</off topic>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *d'en apprendre plus* means *d'apprendre plus de choses*, thus *en* means *choses* and more precisely here, **pieces of information**. That's the " **2. a), fourth ♦** " meaning in the [cnrtl *EN<sup>2</sup>* pronoun entry](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en):

   > *Le déterminant est un quantificateur qui précise une partie par rapport au tout que l'antécédent est supposé représenter*.
2. yes
3. *fonce* means a strong **go ahead**.

Comment: Merci. I wonder if the same goes for the following sentence: « Je n’**en** attendais pas moins de vous. » = « Je n’attendais pas moins **de choses** de vous. » I’m hoping to find out why the word "**en**" needs to replace the phrase "**de choses**" in these sentences. The sentence structure of the former is not easy to wrap my head around.

Comment: Yes, that's the same construction with *en attendre moins*, answer updated with a link.

Comment: This type of *en*, attached to a verb, stands for *de* complements in general: *il y a **des feuilles** => il y **en** a ; il connait la fin **du livre** => il **en** connait la fin ; il vient **de Paris** => il **en** vient.*

Comment: @GAMPUB Merci. Regarding the phrase "il y a **des** (de+les) feuilles" in your comment, even when the **de** refers to "**some**" rather than a preposition "**from/of**", do French speakers usually replace **de** with **en**?

Comment: Yes, it works with indefinite and partitive noun phrases too: *il a mangé **des pommes*** => *il **en** a mangé* ; *il a mangé **du gâteau*** => *il **en** a mangé*.